# JS Not Functioning as Intended

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jQuery plugin called [Sticky Floating Box](http://dropthebit.com/74/sticky-floating-box/) to have a div that floats but is contained within the other div. It appears to work however it doesn't stay within the containing div. I have looked over the scripts [demo page](http://dropthebit.com/demos/stickyfloat/stickyfloat.html) but cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is the JS Initialize Code:

```
$(function() {
   jQuery('.addthis').stickyfloat('update',{ duration:0});
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/CGMXG/1/) showing the issue.

HTML and CSS Below:

```
<div class="header"> HEADER </div>
 <div class="container"> 
  <div class="addthis">
    <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
      <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_floating_style addthis_32x32_style">
            <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
            <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
            <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_share"></a>
            <a class="addthis_button_pinterest_share"></a>
            <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
            <a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=undefined"></script>
      <!-- AddThis Button END -->
  </div>
  <p>ICONS SHOULD STAY <BR> WITHIN THIS GRAY BOX<p>
</div>
<div class="footer"> SHOULD NOT GO BELOW THIS LINE</div> 

.header{
width:400px;
background: #F00;
height:100px;
margin:0 auto;
}
.container{
position:relative;
height:400px;
width:400px;
margin:0 auto;
background: #999;
}
.footer{
height:700px;
width:400px;
background: #F0F;
margin:0 auto;
}
.addthis{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:-50px;
}
```

Comment: Please include all the relevant code in the question. If there's "too much code" to do so, trim it down until you have the smallest example which still reproduces your issue. If for some reason you can't do this, your question isn't suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @meagar - I have included the full code but not sure if it is needed. Most of the CSS isn't required but used for demo purposes. The HTML is the same.

Comment: The problem is that `position: fixed` is getting applied to `.addthis_floating_style` somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do three things to get the jsFiddle to work properly:

`stickyfloat` function needs to be called after the page is ready (and remove the `'update'` part).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.addthis').stickyfloat({ duration:0});
});
```

Add the following css rule:

```
.addthis_floating_style
{
    position:inherit !important;
}
```

Give the `.addthis` div an explicit height and width:

```
.addthis
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:-50px;
    width :36px;
    height:222px;
}
```

Comment: Oops! I forgot the doc ready in the Fiddle. Had that on the page but the rest I did not and it works! Thanks! =>

Comment: One note: it might be better for maintainability (if you add or remove social icons or change the style) to set the height and width of the .addthis div to the height and width of its child div after the social icons load.